# Dual Lattice is a Lattice for the Dual Tori.

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $T=V/L$ be a complex tori with lattice $L$. Consider the set

$$ \overline{\Omega} = \{ h:V \to \mathbb{C}        \text{: h}  \text{  antilinear }   \}$$

I am reading Birkenhake, Christina; Lange, H. (1992), Complex Abelian varieties. The books says that the set

$$ \overline{L} = \{ h\in \overline{\Omega}  :   Im \text{ }h(L)  \subset \mathbb{Z}      \}$$

Is a lattice for $\overline{\Omega}$ i.e a discrete subgroup of maximal rank. I have no idea how to prove it. The book uses the fact that the bilinear map

$$ \overline{\Omega} \times V \to \mathbb{R}, \text{  } (h,v) \mapsto Im \text{ } h(v)  $$

is nondegenerated. I know how to prove the latter fact but not how to use it to prove the proposition. Please help.